# Which Feature / Site Template creates "Site Pages" list?

Tags: 2013

I have got "Pages" list when I create a Site Collection with "Publishing Portal" template, but what to do to have "Site Pages"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Activate the "Wiki Page Home Page" feature to get Site Pages library.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

Wiki Page Home Page with feature id 00bfea71-d8fe-4fec-8dad-01c19a6e4053 with scope Web

Answer (score 2):

**Team Site Template** will have "Site Pages" by default. For other Site templates if you do not see "Site Pages" activate "**Wiki Page Home Page Feature**"  in Manage site Features.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that library is created by activating the feature **Wiki Page Home Page**. That said, you could also create them programmatically if you need to.

Just call the [SPListCollection.EnsureSitePagesLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.ensuresitepageslibrary.aspx) method to ensure the creation of the library as needed.

Answer (score 0):

> what to do to have "Site Pages"?

Open the website with SharePoint Designer, and on the left navigation area (below `Site Objects`) click on the menu item  `Site Pages`. The `Site Pages` library will be created for you, without prompting, if you really want to have it. A bit strange "feature" / behavior in my opinion.